# Full text search using contains shows different results with same database content

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, full-text-search

I have 2 databases with full text search installed. One with real data and the other one just for testing. 
Now my problem is I am having different search results with the same query.

**Databases:**

```
Database 1 = Real Data
Database 2 = Test
```

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT name FROM Recipes WHERE 
CONTAINS(name, 'FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, apple) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL,pie)')
```

**Results For Database 1 and 2:**

[image]

Now when I changed the query from `INFLECTIONAL,pie` to `INFLECTIONAL,pies`:

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT name FROM Recipes WHERE 
CONTAINS(name, 'FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, apple) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL,pies)')
```

**Database 1 Results(No results):**

[image]

**Database 2 Results(Correct results):**

[image]

Why is this happening? What causes this? Is there something wrong with my settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding language in your contains query and see if it works. 1033 stands for english, btw.

```
SELECT name FROM Recipes WHERE 
CONTAINS(name, 'FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, apple) AND FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL,pies)', language 1033)
```